# How can I compare the values from database inside the body and proceed further using Ternary condition

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the values from firestore database and all the details related to user get displayed but when I try to add a condition mentioned below in body it doesn't work.
All I am want is if the user is null, then move user to splash screen and if it is not null then want to check the status, if it is 'blocked' then I want user to go to Block screen other wise the Home Screen with Bottom Tabs. But I don't know why it is not working.
This is the Home Screen with bottom tabs and in this I am trying to compare the values like this but I think the correct values are not getting here.

```
 body: currentUser == null ?
            Center(child: Splash())
                :currentUser.userStatus == 'isBlocked'
                ? BlockUser():
            Center(
              child: Container(),
```

And if put != sign like this then it works.

```
body: currentUser == null ?
            Center(child: Splash())
                :currentUser.userStatus != 'isBlocked'
                ? BlockUser():
            Center(
              child: Container(),
```

I am getting the values this way and it is displays all the data related to user:-

```
CreateAccountData currentUser;

void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _getCurrentUser();
    _getMatches();

    getUser().then((value) {
      currentUser = value;
      userStatus = value.userStatus;
      
    });

  }

Future<CreateAccountData> getUser() async {
    final User user = auth.currentUser;
    return docRef.doc(user.uid).get().then((m) => CreateAccountData.fromDocument(m));

  }
```

Comment: how are you getting value of `currentUser`?

Comment: updated. pls check.

Comment: Can you elaborate what "not working" means?  If you're always seeing that `currentUser` is `null`, it's because you never rebuild your widget after the `getUser` completes and sets `currentUser`.  Use a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: Solved:- I have solved this by saving it as a bool instead of string and now checking "isBlocked"  is true or false and it works fine and then only proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

I think Builder should work best here

```dart
body: Builder(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
     if(currentUser == null){
       return Center(child: Splash())
     }
     if(currentUser.userStatus == 'isBlocked'){
       return BlockUser();
     }

     return Center(child: Container();

   },
),
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html

Comment: tried this but not working, the problem is somewhere reading the data I think. If I put != sign instead of == then it takes to block screen but I want to match the value with particular keyword like in this case it  == isBlocked.

Comment: Solved:- I have solved this by saving it as a bool instead of string and now checking "isBlocked"  is true or false and it works fine and then only proceed further. Thanks for ur effort and time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Future` builder to wait for future to complete as

```
body: FutureBuilder(
      future: getUser(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
            if(currentUser == null){
                return Splash();
            }else if(currentUser.userStatus == 'isBlocked'){
                return BlockUser();
            }else{
                return Container();
            }
          }else{
            return _loadingWidget();
          }
        },
    );
```

And update your `getUser()` as

```
Future<CreateAccountData> getUser() async {
    final User user = auth.currentUser;
    currentUser  = CreateAccountData.fromDocument(await docRef.doc(user.uid).get());
}
```

Also the remove the `getUser` call from `initState` method

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _getCurrentUser();
    _getMatches();
  }
```

**Problem:** The problem with your code is that you build method is not waiting for future to complete and you are facing issues check user status and your code always navigate to splash.

Comment: Still the result is same and if I add != sign instead of == then it goes to other screen but here I want to compare the value and if matches then move to another screen other wise not.

Comment: then make sure `docRef.doc(user.uid).get()` line returns the document of user detail.

Comment: I think it is returning data that is why it doesn't go to splash screen and displays all the details related to user.

Comment: what is required ? if there is data exists

Comment: Its a Home Screen with bottom navigation index and if the data of currentUser.userStatus says in data base it is 'isblocked' then move to block screen other wise user can navigate anywhere.

Comment: then else part will return the home screen widget simply.

Comment: Solved:- I have solved this by saving it as a bool instead of string and now checking "isBlocked"  is true or false and it works fine and then only proceed further. Thanks for ur effort and time.